# I have two separate branches with different histories. How do I take changes from a feature branch and merge to both?

Tags: git

Like the title says, I have a develop branch and a maintenance branch. The release branch has a different history than the maintenance branch.

A new feature branch which is based off of the develop branch was created and worked on and a pull request was created to the develop branch.

But now the problem is, we want to take the commits made in the feature branch and apply it to the maintenance branch. And we can't merge the feature branch to the maintenance branch because it has different histories and we have some code in the develop branch we don't want in the maintenance branch. How would we go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the changes introduced by a bunch of specific commits that occured at certain times over history without keeping trace of this origin, you can use

```
git cherry-pick <your commits>
```

… to reapply them.

If you want to reconstruct a brand new feature branch based on the previous one and just want to pick up roughly all commits as they are, apart a few exceptions that need to be adapted first, you may want to use

```
git rebase -i
```

instead.